# Truncate empty table can free the memory?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have some cache tables that are already empty by a delete, if I try to truncate a table with the DROP STORAGE option, the memory will be free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707):

> By default, Oracle Database also performs the following tasks:
>
> - Deallocates all space used by the removed rows except that specified by the MINEXTENTS storage parameter

The DROP STORAGE option has exactly the same effect as it is the default.